# jqgrid - how do I get a reference to the column's edittype element upon resizeStop event?

Tags: jqgrid, resize

main goal:
upon *resizeStop*, I need to resize the element's width inside the cell. e.g. *edittype="select"*

here's the scenario:
1) there's a jqgrid, has columns, let's say in column 3 has *edittype="select"*.
2) user resize the column 3
3) after resizing, the *resizeStop(newwidth, index)* event
**4) inside the *resizeStop* event, want to get a reference to all *select* element of the given index. Then resize it appropriately.**

problem:
I don't know on how to implement the number 4...
please guide me or give me hints to investigate.
thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            resizeStop: function (newwidth, index) {
                var selectedRowId = jQuery("#jqgridElementId").getGridParam('selrow');
                if(selectedRowId) {
                    //resize combobox proportionate to column size
                    var selectElement = $('[id="' + selectedRowId + '_' + (index-1) + '"][role="select"]');
                    if(selectElement.length > 0){
                        $(selectElement).width(newwidth);
                    }
                }
            },
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                if(id ){

                    //resize combobox proportionate to column size
                    var rowSelectElements = $('[id^="' + id + '_"][role="select"]');
                    if(rowSelectElements.length > 0) {
                        $(rowSelectElements).each(function(index, element){
                            var name = $(element).attr('name');
                            var columnElement = $('#jqgridElementId_' + name);
                            if(columnElement.length > 0) {
                                var columnWidth = $(columnElement).width();
                                $(element).width(columnWidth);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method it is probably what you need.